# Create advertising hide just one day (have cookies) when user click close

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to create advertising hide just one day (have cookies) when user clicks close. When user click the close button, I want div with class box-download not showing again until 1 days

This is my HTML

```html
<div class="box-download" id="showup-downloadbox" style="display:none;">
  <div class="ebook">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>
    <div class="book-img-download">
        <img style="width:24%;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/download-gratis-e-book-8kunci-sukses-implementasi-sistem-erp.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="book-txt-download">
        <h3>FREE ! Download E-Book Now<br /><b>8 Tips Successful ERP System Implementation</b></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-download-book">
        <form id="contact_form" method="post" action="http://www.sap-business-one-tips.com/wp-content/themes/sap-b1-tips/mailer.php">
            <div class="form-group" style="">
                <input type="name" name="name" class="input-name" placeholder="Name*">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-email" placeholder="Email*">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg'><br>
                <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
                <br>
                <input id="captcha_code" name="captcha_code" type="text">
                <br>
                Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();' style="color:#022dc3;">here</a> to refresh.
            </div>
            <p><input type="submit" value="SEND" class="submit-partner"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

js code http://jsfiddle.net/t2kbLgxd/1/

Can somebody help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far? show your javascript / jquery code

Comment: Hi @ViswanathPolaki so far i can just show the popup, when using delay javascript to show div content. Now the div show but when user submit or click close button, that's showing again when user refresh.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki this my js code http://jsfiddle.net/t2kbLgxd/1/ but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code using jquery and jquery.cookie.js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (!($.cookie("hide") === 1)) {
      $('#showup-downloadbox').delay(100).show(0);
    }
  });
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#close').click(function (e) {
      $.cookie("hide", "1", {expires: 1});
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: after using jquery.cookie.js and jquery-3.3.1.min.js my website broken. just show the popup, and cookie not working (show again after click close button and refresh). Any ideas? i will appreciate

Comment: have you downloaded the jquery.cookie.js from https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ (right hand side there will be a download button). Extract the zip and place your jquery.cookie.js (found in the folder) in the same folder where your code is present.

Comment: yes, i use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js

Comment: change the delay(100) to delay(5000)

Comment: Change the delay 100 to 5000, it's just delay the popup to show. this error in my console  "TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function"

Comment: work perfectly when i combine the function into 1 jQuery(document).ready(function ()